Calculating nth permutation without repetition efficiently, with variable number of elements
I know I can use the factorial number system to calculate ordered permutations of a set efficiently, given a constant length (for example, [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), ..., (3, 2, 1)]), but can it be used for non-constant lengths?
For example, my set is {a, b, c}. and the function input/outputs:
f(0) = a
f(1) = b
f(2) = c
f(3) = ab
f(4) = ac
f(5) = ba
...

That is, after the permutations of size 1, there comes permutations of size 2, then size 3, etc., to infinity.

If f(x) = y and the set $S$ is {a, b, c}, then given $x = 999$:

subtract the set size $3!$ ($999 - 3! = 993$) to "complete" all permutations of size 1
repeat this with $4!$ ($993 - 4! = 969$) to "complete" all permutations of size 2
then $5!$, $969 - 5! = 849$
then $849 - 6! = 129$

since we repeated 4 times, we have completed all permutations up to size 4.
This means that $999$ is for a permutation of size 5. You can now use the factorial number system with $x = 129$ to calculate ordered permutations of a set of a constant size ($5$).
